# Debugger isn't stopping at breakpoint and app is crashing

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I want to look my app via Debugger. When adding breakpoints, debugger isn't stopping at breakpoints and app crashing. But when launching app without debugger, everything works like a charm.

Only I saw this error logs on LogCat

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
07-28 09:54:28.793      503-590/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@3e2c039b attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@16337808
07-28 09:54:28.993  10031-10041/? W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.607ms
07-28 09:54:30.093    503-10176/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.companyapp/.MainActivity
07-28 09:54:30.093    503-10176/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.companyapp/.LoginScreen
07-28 09:54:30.773     781-1201/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: jb, destroying layer...
07-28 09:54:30.773     781-1201/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: jb, destroying layer...
07-28 09:54:52.623    3318-3318/? W/LinkRimService﹕ ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
07-28 09:54:53.053      503-523/? W/ProcessCpuTracker﹕ Skipping unknown process pid 10374
```

How to force debugger to stop at breakpoints ?

Thanks for helpings.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by repeatedly looping through the following:

- Unplug and plug the device back
- Running adb kill-server and adb start-server
- Restart Android Studio
- Restart Computer

Comment: This was the problem with anrdoid studio 1.0 and 1.1. I generally gets is solved by unplug and plug device back. You can try two more thing                            1. Update the android studio to latest and 2. Restart android device

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a workaround:

- Run the app from Android Studio (**not** [image], but [image]).
- Once the app is up and running, attach the debugger to the app using the **Attach debugger to Android process** command on the **Run** menu.

Breakpoints will now work properly.

This workaround has limitations -- you can't set a breakpoint in, say, `Application.onCreate`, or any other startup code.